# make IntelliJ Idea remember the updates/changes of modules' dependencies scopes?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am running a java/spark project from IntelliJ idea (community 2019.2) on macbook pro.

I use maven.

The scope of dependencies of modules have four types:

```
 compile
 test
 build
 provided
```

When I build the modules, I always got the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike
```

Or, other classes.

I have to change the scope of the dependency of the class from

```
 provided
```

to

```
 compile
```

But, there are so many dependencies, it is really boring to change them one by one. 
Also, whenever I use

```
 invalidate cache and restart
```

All setting for the scope will be reset, I have to repeat the scope setting.

How can I only need to change scopes for all dependencies only one time and make IntelliJ remember what I have changed for scopes?

Thanks

Comment: as you speak about dependendency scopes, then what build tool do you use here? Prehaps Maven? Also, you're speaking about many modules. Then what is your configuration of this multimodule project? Going with "invalidate cache and restart" or re-import project in IntelliJ starts the build scripts or IDEA config file to configure the project.

Comment: @itwasntme, I use maven, please let me know what configuration of this multimodule project that you need to know ? thanks

Comment: Necessary part of `pom.xml` files of modules and root project. The root project should declare the modules, then it's possible to use one module as dependency in another module. Also "I have to change the scope of the dependency of the class from", how do you change the scope of that class/module?

Comment: I can open "file"  --> "project structure" --> "modules" --> "dependencies" in IntelliJ and changes the scopes.

Comment: Bum, there it is. And I've said it already. IntelliJ doesn't always modify the `pom.xml` files for you, in most of cases it only changes its own project configuration, so after `invalidate...` it tries to reimport project basing on POM. Post necessary parts of your `pom.xml` files and current project structure.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Maven you must not change the configuration of the dependencies and other project structure settings (like directories, compiler etc) in the IDE UI. You change it in Maven pom.xml file. So to set the dependency scope in [Maven dependency configuration](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-dependency-scopes/) using `<scope>` element e.g.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```